# Using Amazon Redshift for analytics for a Django app with Postgresql as the database

Tags: django, postgresql, architecture, amazon-redshift

I have a working Django web application that currently uses Postgresql as the database. Moving forward I would like to perform some analytics on the data and also generate reports etc. I would like to make use of Amazon Redshift as the data warehouse for the above goals.

In order to not affect the performance of the existing django web application, I was thinking of writing a NEW Django application that essentially would leverage a READ-ONLY replica of the Postgresql database and continuously write data from read-only replicas to the Amazon Redshift. My thinking is that perhaps the NEW Django application can be used to handle some/all of the Extract, Transform and Load functions

My questions are as follows:
1. Does the Django ORM work well with Amazon Redshift? If yes, how does one handle the model schema translations? Any pointers in this regard would be greatly appreciated.
2. Is there any better alternative to achieve the goals listed above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at pgbouncer-rr https://github.com/awslabs/pgbouncer-rr-patch . This may help.

Comment: thank you @JonScott . Just one follow-up. Are you suggesting that if I do end up using pgbouncer-rr then I wouldn't need to create the NEW django app that I refer to above?

Comment: replicate your postgres to redshift using DMS, then set up pgbouncer rr to route the analytics queries - and leave django as is.. something like that :)